# Create multicategory timeline chart in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, charts, microsoft-excel-2016, timeline

I'd like to create an Excel chart showing on the x axis the dates from 1943 to 2021 and on the y axis the relevant category which follows a specific timeframe.

I.e. from 1/1/1943 to 18/01/1943 category 1 and from 19/01/1943 to 20/03/1945 category 2 and so on

Below you can see an example.

[image: table example]

Basically I would like to create a timeline showing Italian prime ministers in charge during their mandate. As an example, take this image from wikipedia which exactly shows what i would like to create

Timeline of Italian PM from 1861 to 1945:
[image: timeline of Italian PM from 1861 to 1945]

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by adding another column to your data. "Days" is the number of days from the subsequent date to the previous date. And input an end date at the bottom, which I used 12/31/2017 in my data. This is needed for column C calculation.

So, **cell C2 formula** is:

```
=B3-B2
```

Drag down your formula.

Then create a Stacked Bar chart using either blank template or your data. Go to Select Data on your chart and remove anything you already have in there. You're going to add 2 series.

Add Date (Series Name is Date and Series Values are B2:B11).
Then add another series for Days (Series Name is Days and Series Values are C2:C11).

Then, with the Select Data Source box still open, click on the Edit Horizontal axis labels, and select your Category (A2:A11).

Your chart should now look like this:

[image]

Next, right-click on your y-axis, Select Format Axis, and click on the box for Categories in Reverse Order. This will get A to the top.

Next, we'll remove the Orange fill. Right-click on that series and go to Format Data Series. In Fill, select No Fill.

Now your chart should look like this:

[image]

Next, let's format the x-axis. Right click on that x-axis and format axis. Set the bounds as such:

Minimum is the excel numeric value of the start date. In this case, 1/1/2012 is 40909. To get this value, just copy your start date in another cell and change the format to General. Same trick for the Maximum, where 12/31/2017 = 43100. You may need to fudge around with this since you are using such old dates.

If you want to only show the Year on the axis label, then change your Date column format to custom YYYY.

Our chart now appears as:

[image]

Lastly, right click on your blue bars and click Add data labels. You'll see they add the number days. Fix this by then right-clicking on the label and Format Data Labels. Select "Category Name" checkbox and then deselect Value checkbox. Change the position to perhaps "Inside End". OR, you can move them more by selecting a label and dragging it to the right, then click on the Clone Current Label box in the Format Data Label window.

Last step is to delete your y-axis since you don't need it if you are using labels.

Final output:

[image]